# how to resolve Undeclared array referenced error in sas?

Tags: sas

Consider the following codes:

```
data;
x=var{89,90,78,98,87,786,69,90,92,88};
y=std{89,90,78,98,87,76,69,90,92,88};
run;
```

I get the following errors:

1    data;
2    x=var{89,90,78,98,87,786,69,90,92,88};
ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: var.
ERROR: Variable var has not been declared as an array.
3    y=std{89,90,78,98,87,76,69,90,92,88};
ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: std.
ERROR: Variable std has not been declared as an array.
4    run;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS the arguments to a function are enclosed in parenthesis.

Try

```
data;
  x = var (89,90,78,98,87,76,69,90,92,88);   * Variance;
  y = std (89,90,78,98,87,76,69,90,92,88);   * Standard deviation;
run;
```

The ERROR: messages appear because array subscripting references are made with bracketing square brackets (`[]`), curly braces (`{}`) or parenthesis (`()`).  Declared array names can override function names, so be careful with that.

Your source code

```
x = var{89,90,78,98,87,786,69,90,92,88};
```

is actually telling SAS you want to retrieve a value from a **10-dimensional** array.

Functions can also process arrays if you add a `of` to the arguments list.

```
data x;
    * initialize temporary array of 10 values;
    array m(10) _temporary_ (89,90,78,98,87,76,69,90,92,88);

    * measure the array of values;
    x = var (of m(*));
    y = std (of m(*));
run;
```